# MySQL LEFT OUTER JOIN to include third table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN on three tables. I have complete the first part to join two tables but I am stuck on intergarting the third table.

What I need is the "Status" field for the NXLHR_Valid to be included in the first query.

Below are my to queries, how would I include the SECOND query into the FIRST query

FIRST QUERY

```
SELECT NXLHR_SequenceNo_default.SeqNo, NXLHR_SequenceNo_default.SeqHeader, NXLHR_SequenceNo_default.SeqText, NXLHR_Hist.UniqueID, NXLHR_Hist.Room, NXLHR_Hist.Status, NXLHR_Hist.Water, NXLHR_Hist.AuditBy 
FROM NXLHR_SequenceNo_default 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  NXLHR_Hist 
ON NXLHR_SequenceNo_default.SeqID = NXLHR_Hist.SeqID 
AND NXLHR_Hist.UniqueID = 'NXLHR01031472477564' 
WHERE NXLHR_SequenceNo_default.SeqActive = 1
ORDER BY NXLHR_SequenceNo_default.OrderID
```

SECOND QUERY

```
SELECT NXLHR_Valid.UniqueID, NXLHR_Valid.Status 
FROM NXLHR_Valid 
WHERE NXLHR_Valid.UniqueID = 'NXLHR01031472477564'
```

Any help would be great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would be better to describe your business goal rather than how to outer join three tables. There is no problem in joining three tables together with outer joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.SeqNo
     , d.SeqHeader
     , d.SeqText
     , h.UniqueID
     , h.Room
     , h.Status
     , h.Water
     , h.AuditBy 
     , v.Status 
  FROM NXLHR_SequenceNo_default d
  LEFT 
  JOIN NXLHR_Hist h
    ON h.SeqID = d.SeqID 
   AND h.UniqueID = 'NXLHR01031472477564' 
  LEFT
  JOIN NXLHR_Valid v
    ON v.UniqueID = h.UniqueID  
 WHERE d.SeqActive = 1
 ORDER 
    BY d.OrderID
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, works perfectly. I have learned something. Again thanks.

Comment: (hopefully several things!)